# Провести группировку объектов в многомерном массиве/ json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Имеем:

```
[
  {
    "EventStartDate": "17/10/2008",
    "EventType": "Restricted",
    "Event": "My Forum",
    "SessionStartTime": "18:00",
    "City": "Ryazan",
    "TypeSession": "1on1",
    "RowCount": 0
  },
  {
    "EventStartDate": "17/10/2008",
    "EventType": "Restricted",
    "Event": "My Forum",
    "SessionStartTime": "15:10",
    "City": "London",
    "TypeSession": "3on1",
    "RowCount": 1
  },
  {
    "EventStartDate": "24/11/2008",
    "EventType": "Conference",
    "Event": "AAA Test Event",
    "SessionStartTime": "15:10",
    "City": "Paris",
    "TypeSession": "Meeting",
    "RowCount": 2
  },
  {
    "EventStartDate": "24/11/2008",
    "EventType": "Conference",
    "Event": "AAA Test Event",
    "SessionStartTime": "16:10",
    "City": "Moscow",
    "TypeSession": "Breakfast",
    "RowCount": 3
  }
]
```

Необходимо произвести группировку сессий по дате, по типам ивента, по названию ивента.

Конечный JSON, кажется правильно собран:

```
"17/10/2008": {
        "Restricted": {
            "My Forum": {
                "18:00": {
                    "City": "Ryazan",
                    "TypeSession": "1on1",
                    "RowCount": 0
                },
                "15:10": {
                    "City": "London",
                    "TypeSession": "3on1",
                    "RowCount": 1
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "24/11/2008": {
        "Conference": {
            "AAA Test Event": {
                "15:10": {
                    "City": "Paris",
                    "TypeSession": "Meeting",
                    "RowCount": 2
                },
                "16:10": {
                    "City": "Moscow",
                    "TypeSession": "Breakfast",
                    "RowCount": 3
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Мой скрипт цикла перебора массива, некорректен.

```
<script>       
    var arr2 = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
        if (arr2[arr1[i].EventStartDate] && arr2[arr1[i].EventStartDate].EventStartDate) {
            for (n in arr1[i]) {
                if (n != 'EventStartDate') {
                    arr2[arr1[i].EventStartDate][n] = (arr2[arr1[i].EventStartDate][n]) ? arr2[arr1[i].EventStartDate][n] + ";" + arr1[i][n] : arr1[i][n];
                }
            }
        } else {
            arr2[arr1[i].EventStartDate] = arr1[i];
        }

    }
    console.log('result', arr2);
</script>
```

но он делает не то что я ожидал, мне кажется я иду не верным путем, направьте меня)

Comment: добавьте пример настоящего исходного json и пример того, что должно получиться на выходе

Comment: @Grundy добавил.

Comment: не вижу примера начального json? да и конечного json тоже не видно. Для каких данных приведен конечный html?

Comment: @Grundy теперь точно как просил)

Comment: Отличный вопрос. Есть данные, есть желаемый результат, есть код. )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для различных группировок удобно использовать функцию [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```js
var data = [{
  "EventStartDate": "17/10/2008",
  "EventType": "Restricted",
  "Event": "My Forum",
  "SessionStartTime": "18:00",
  "City": "Ryazan",
  "TypeSession": "1on1",
  "RowCount": 0
}, {
  "EventStartDate": "17/10/2008",
  "EventType": "Restricted",
  "Event": "My Forum",
  "SessionStartTime": "15:10",
  "City": "London",
  "TypeSession": "3on1",
  "RowCount": 1
}, {
  "EventStartDate": "24/11/2008",
  "EventType": "Conference",
  "Event": "AAA Test Event",
  "SessionStartTime": "15:10",
  "City": "Paris",
  "TypeSession": "Meeting",
  "RowCount": 2
}, {
  "EventStartDate": "24/11/2008",
  "EventType": "Conference",
  "Event": "AAA Test Event",
  "SessionStartTime": "16:10",
  "City": "Moscow",
  "TypeSession": "Breakfast",
  "RowCount": 3
}];

var result = data.reduce(function(acc, cur) {
  var eventDate = acc[cur.EventStartDate]; //группируем по дате
  if (!eventDate) {
    eventDate = acc[cur.EventStartDate] = {};
  }
  var eventType = eventDate[cur.EventType]; //группируем по типу
  if (!eventType) {
    eventType = eventDate[cur.EventType] = {};
  }
  var eventName = eventType[cur.Event]; //группируем по названию
  if (!eventName) {
    eventName = eventType[cur.Event] = {};
  }

  // если нужно хранить весь объект а не какие-то поля. то можно просто присвоить cur
  // eventName[cur.SessionStartTime] = cur;

  eventName[cur.SessionStartTime] = {
    "City": cur.City,
    "TypeSession": cur.TypeSession,
    "RowCount": cur.RowCount
  };
  return acc;
}, {});

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, null, 2) + '</pre>');
```

Можно. также, чуть обобщить, как в соседнем ответе. Но на мой взгляд читаемость ухудшилась.

```js
var data = [{
  "EventStartDate": "17/10/2008",
  "EventType": "Restricted",
  "Event": "My Forum",
  "SessionStartTime": "18:00",
  "City": "Ryazan",
  "TypeSession": "1on1",
  "RowCount": 0
}, {
  "EventStartDate": "17/10/2008",
  "EventType": "Restricted",
  "Event": "My Forum",
  "SessionStartTime": "15:10",
  "City": "London",
  "TypeSession": "3on1",
  "RowCount": 1
}, {
  "EventStartDate": "24/11/2008",
  "EventType": "Conference",
  "Event": "AAA Test Event",
  "SessionStartTime": "15:10",
  "City": "Paris",
  "TypeSession": "Meeting",
  "RowCount": 2
}, {
  "EventStartDate": "24/11/2008",
  "EventType": "Conference",
  "Event": "AAA Test Event",
  "SessionStartTime": "16:10",
  "City": "Moscow",
  "TypeSession": "Breakfast",
  "RowCount": 3
}];

var result = data.reduce(function(acc, cur) {
  var group = acc.groupKeys.reduce(function(groupObject, currentGroupKey) {
    var g = groupObject[cur[currentGroupKey]];
    if (!g) g = groupObject[cur[currentGroupKey]] = {};
    return g;
  }, acc.result);

  group[cur[acc.lastGroupKey]] = acc.selectKeys.reduce(function(selectObject, selectKey) {
    selectObject[selectKey] = cur[selectKey];
    return selectObject;
  }, {});

  return acc;
}, {
  lastGroupKey: "SessionStartTime",
  groupKeys: ["EventStartDate", "EventType", "Event"],
  selectKeys: ["City", "TypeSession", "RowCount"],
  result: {}
}).result;

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, null, 2) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: Спасибо! Первый вариант мне тоже больше нравится и совсем понятен, ничего сложного. Впервые пытаюсь работать с JSON.  А не подскажешь как теперь развесить на html разметку, ведь теперь нет явных ключей как название полей, а данные могут быть любыми вообще.

Comment: @re_void, цикл `for...in` обходит по всем ключам объектов. Кроме того, можно попробовать пропустить построение конечного js и вместо него сразу собирать объект jQuery, который потом вставить куда надо. Но тут еще конечную разметку надо смотреть

Comment: для `for...in` ключи же мне не известны, а разметка ровно как каждый блок по Дате, а дальше по элементам порядок как и в JSON.

Comment: @re_void, `for..in` - как раз ключи и возвращает, вот и делайте _каждый блок по Дате, а дальше по элементам порядок как и в JSON_ :)

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо большое.)

Answer (score 1):

```js
let source = JSON.parse(`[{
  "EventStartDate": "17/10/2008",
  "EventType": "Restricted",
  "Event": "My Forum",
  "SessionStartTime": "18:00",
  "City": "Ryazan",
  "TypeSession": "1on1",
  "RowCount": 0
}, {
  "EventStartDate": "17/10/2008",
  "EventType": "Restricted",
  "Event": "My Forum",
  "SessionStartTime": "15:10",
  "City": "London",
  "TypeSession": "3on1",
  "RowCount": 1
}, {
  "EventStartDate": "24/11/2008",
  "EventType": "Conference",
  "Event": "AAA Test Event",
  "SessionStartTime": "15:10",
  "City": "Paris",
  "TypeSession": "Meeting",
  "RowCount": 2
}, {
  "EventStartDate": "24/11/2008",
  "EventType": "Conference",
  "Event": "AAA Test Event",
  "SessionStartTime": "16:10",
  "City": "Moscow",
  "TypeSession": "Breakfast",
  "RowCount": 3
}]`),
    result = {},
    data = [
      ['EventStartDate', 'EventType', 'Event', 'SessionStartTime'], // Цепочка вложенностей; порядок важен, ибо зависит результат
      ['City', 'TypeSession', 'RowCount'] // Ключи по которым нужно помещать в результатЪ
    ];

source.forEach(e => { // Перебираем все элементы событий
  let ref = result, // Ставим локальную ссылку на результат
      obj = {};
  
  for(let id in data[1])
    obj[data[1][id]] = e[data[1][id]]; // Создаём объект с значениями из data[1], который положим в результат
  
  data[0].slice(0, -1).forEach(id => { // Создаём/получаем по очереди всю цепочку (кроме последнего элемента) из data[0]
    if(!(e[id] in ref))
      ref[e[id]] = {};
    
    ref = ref[e[id]];
  });
  
  ref[e[data[0][data[0].length - 1]]] = obj; // Вставляем событие по последнему ключу из data[0]
});

console.dir(result);
```

**Note:** В условиях ничего не сказано про множественные мероприятия одного типа, даты, названия и времени. Т. е. если всё в цепочке совпадёт, то последнее мероприятие перезапишет остальные. Хотел было помещать их в массив, если совпадут, но решил без самодеятельности.
Да и вряд ли они вообще должны совпадать, верно?

Comment: да, полностью совпасть не может, может совпадать только: дата, тип, имя ивента, остально уже полюбому в отдельных ветках. Спасибо отличный вариант! только на формат даты\время ругается, но я у себя поправил. Впервые с JSON имею дело, как бы теперь это html шаблон это адекватно натянуть.